# How to using Routing middleware in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I add in my services ASP.NET Core Routing middleware for my Razor Pages project, but how I create route "/Product" to redirect into page using Routing middleware.
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please try to explain what you're looking for in more detail ([ask]). I suggest showing the code you have for adding the routing middleware along with explaining what the page is you want to redirect to.

Comment: I added intro services Routing middleware, but How I redirect path "/home" to page home using RouteHandler and routing middleware to mapping without standart Razor Pages.

Comment: The path /home automatically maps to the page "home" in Razor Pages. you don't need to do anything with routing middleware. Perhaps this article on Routing in Razor Pages will help you understand how it works: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing. If not, you should provide more detail on the structure and name of your pages and how you want to map URLs to them.